# Intrinsics and registers(SSE)

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse

I have question about SSE.

As I can understand, SSE consist of XMM registers. And (as I can understand) if I need move some value from some part of SSE to other part - I have to use assembler language. For example `movdqa xmm7, xmm6`. But it doesn't work.

I need to move value to another cell [image]
What should I do?

Comment: That's a shuffle, and if you are using intrinsics, you don't need asm for that. See [_mm_shuffle_epi32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f67xbk(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Jester Thank you very much. It works.

Comment: Note that @Jester's comment is not limited to the shuffle operation; you don't need asm to use any of SSE, really. The `<xmmintrin.h>` header defines also the types (`__m128`, `__m128i`, and `__m128d`) that correspond to what an XMM register can hold, as well as the intrinsics operating on them, corresponding to SSE instructions.

Comment: Note that there are separate shuffle instructions for shuffling integer values and for shuffling floating point values. On some processors, there's a small time penalty for switching between integer and floating point operations.

Answer (score 1):

When you write in C++, you use intrinsics, and it is up to the compiler to allocate registers, the same as with usual non-vector code.

Related:

- [Understanding how the instrinsic functions for SSE use memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29147932/2945027)
- [SIMD Intrinsics and Persistent Variables/State](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48407505/2945027)
- [Pointer to result of AVX load (_mm256_load_si256)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69870629/2945027)

---

The values you see in debugger watch window are representations of a single xmm value, that may be in a register or in memory. In case of registers, is not two different xmm registers, so `movdqa xmm7, xmm6` is irrelevant.

The fact that you see in in named `tt` variable indicates that it is in memory, the Visual Studio debugger most of the times cannot show a variable that is implemented in a register. (It may be due to debug build, whereas in release it will be in a register).

`_m128i` type is defined as union of arrays, because it may be seen by different operations as consisting of vectors with different element size. You are looking at vector of 32-bit values. To rearrange components there's 32-bit shuffle `_mm_shuffle_epi32`, as pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414768/intrinsics-and-registerssse#comment77790012_45414768).

The same shuffle can be used to swap 64-bit values. For other value sizes (smaller than 32) there's 8-bit shuffle `_mm_shuffle_epi8`. It requires SSSE3 though. If you want to keep SSE2 as a baseline, the goal can be achieved in multiple intrinsics: there's `_mm_extract_epi16`/`_mm_insert_epi16`, also some shuffles can be achieved by using a sequence of `_mm_unpack` operations and/or shifts.